# How to use www.addthis.com

Tags: c#, javascript

I need to use addthis.com plugin to my website, when they click the email link, i need to pass my own data to the plugin, that needs to be sent to client.

Is there anyway to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Have you opened www.addthis.com?

Answer (score 2):

Goto `www.addthis.com`

1. Select Service
2. Select Button Style
3. Choose if you want analytic (to track button performance you need to register)
4. Click on **"Get This Button"** button (if you selected analytic, you will have to register)

Get html code and use on your site.